Why Do We Use python3 in Mac and python in Windows in the Terminal to Run or Install Something?
I've noticed that when I use the terminal, the command for running Python scripts or installing packages is different on macOS and Windows. On macOS, I usually have to type python3, but on Windows, I just use python.
I'm curious why there's this difference.

Check out Python or Python3. What is the difference? for some related discussions.

It's not correct.
If you install python3 (either MacOS or Windows) you type python3 and if you have python2 you type python.
You can check which version you have in the terminal (or cmd):
python -V

or you can type in your IDE the following:
import sys
print(sys.version)

For me the cmd didn't result with an answer, while the IDE comes up with python 3.10.11 so try the both.
Sources:
Link1
Link2
